# VSCode extensions: code-outline for Perl .cgi files

Tags: perl, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for Perl (on Debian 9). I have installed VSCode extensions:

- [Code Outline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=patrys.vscode-code-outline) (by Patryk Zawadzki);
- [Perl](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=henriiik.vscode-perl) (by Henrik Sjooh).

Extension *code-outline* works great for .pl files but doesn't for .cgi files (although both .pl and .cgi recognized as Perl files). I can't find any info for how to fix it. Maybe someone did the same already? How to make *code-outline* extension works for .cgi files too?

Comment: Downvoters, do not close. See <https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic> : "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include links to the tools you're using.

Answer (score 1):

File extensions don't really matter.

In the bottom right of the Visual Studio Code window will be a menu where you can pick the language you are working on.

It won't default to Perl for files with a `.cgi` extension, but you can change that.

[image: The menu is between the End Of Line setting and the Feedback smiley face]

Comment: I have vscode 1.22.1 and both .cgi and .pl are recognized as perl files.